# is it correct to say "within its capacity" and "wellbeing/welfare" for the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence-construction

(context) The sentence I was trying to write is: "I hope each one of us is doing the best, ***within its capacity***, for the ***wellbeing(welfare)*** of our friend.".

Is it better to replace ***"within its capacity"*** for ***"..is doing the best he/she can"*** or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Though the area might be highly grayish rather than black and white, I believe that the commas before and after the phrase "within its capacity" are unnecessary.

Comment: unless they're all dogs or robots, I'd use 'their' not 'its'

Comment: I agree with Tetsujin against the usage of its - singular '[they](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7k-20y5WKU)' (and its possessive counterpart 'their') is more elegant than he/she, his/her etc.

Comment: On purely semantic grounds I think ***within his capacity*** is totally superfluous. No matter how hard you strive, or how good your best is, it can never be *beyond* your capacity. Note that idiomatically, each one of us would be doing ***their** best*, not ***the** best*.

Answer (score 1):

I would use **within *his/her* capacity**. *Its* is used to refer to things other than people.

The phrase *is doing the best he/she can* works just fine as well.

The word *well-being* and *welfare* are both correct, but the first is spelt with a hyphen, not in one word.